# Why do I get no option to boot either Ubuntu or Windows after UBUNTU 12.1 installation for a dual boot (PC automatically loads windows xp sp3)?

Tags: dual-boot, hard-drive, startup, windows-xp

I've just Installed Ubuntu 12.10. When asked to remove dvd to restart there was no boot option menu and PC started to load windows.

*Checkdisk* ran and displayed multiple messages, eg. `Deleting orphan file record segment 123416`.

In Windows XP my C:\ was reduced by the amount of space allocated to ubuntu partitions.
I accessed boot menu and there was only the option for Normal windows start up and windows recovery start up.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair. Sometimes the installer cannot properly place the GRUB (first-level boot menu) on the hard disk. Repairing it is often as simple as running the Boot-Repair tool.